How to create an installer that installs Python and all dependencies for my Python project on a fresh machine?
tl;dr: I am not looking to make a single executable file to run the whole program(although I will need it later) but rather a file that will install all the dependencies (if it does not exist already)
I have a Python project with the following structure:
A main script (main.py) in the root folder which starts the application:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    os.chdir(script_dir)

    myRoot = tk.Tk()
    myApp = Pk_MainApp(myRoot)
    myApp.Run()

The project relies on several dependencies (e.g., opencv, tkinter, xml.etree.ElementTree, and others).
I have many imports across different .py files, and the project also includes subfolders containing other scripts.
I generated a requirements.txt file using pipreqs, but it seems incomplete — not all imports are captured. My goal is to create an installer (batch file or .exe) that will:
Install Python on a "virgin" machine (one that has no Python or libraries installed).
Install all the necessary Python libraries and dependencies listed in requirements.txt.
Ensure that after running this installer, the project can be executed without any manual setup, simply by running main.py.
My current approach involved running:
pipreqs path/to/my/folder --force

However, I noticed that it didn’t catch all of the required dependencies, such as tkinter.
Question:
Is there a way to automate the installation of Python itself, along with all required libraries and dependencies for my project?
Ideally, I'd like to put everything on a USB drive and have a single .bat or .exe that, when run, will install Python, the required dependencies, and allow the project to run. What’s the best way to achieve this?

tkinter should be included as a part of Python standard libraries and therefore shouldn't need separate installation.

These are really two independent problems: 1) the correctness of your requirements.txt (which should not contain tkinter as commented above and nobody on this site can verify it anyway) 2) a batch file that contains the two commands to install Python and all your required libraries. I voted to close as "needs more focus"

Sounds like you're looking for PyInstaller or cx_freeze.

Dropbox is an example of a standalone Python application that doesn't actually require Python being installed on its own... And there's a portable version. It bundles the interpreter within itself... Recommend you create a pyproject.toml for packaging, not just a requirements file https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

@matszwecja - That's not always true. I just wiped a windows machine and installed the latest Ubuntu, and tkinter was not part of the python install. I actually had to use deadsnakes to get tkinter installed.I installed python 3.12 in tandem and tkinter wasn't part of that install either.

@OysterShucker Erm, you'd just install python3-tk, you don't need deadsnakes. It's a separate package on Ubuntu/Debian to avoid pulling in TCL/TK and all of its dependencies when not needed.

@AKX - you're right (halfway)! For the upgrade to the python that came with Ubuntu that worked, but when upgrading the python3.12 version that I installed, it did not work, and I had to use deadsnakes. install python3.12-tk failed to find a suitable match.

@AKX from the first sentence in the post: "P.S I am not looking to make a single executable file to run the whole program"

@matszwecja Right, I was basing things on the title: "How to create an installer that installs Python [...]"

tkinter is part of the standard library, but not all distribution put all of the standard library in a single package. (tkinter is the usual thing left out, since it requires non-Python dependencies anyway.)

I've done this with python and it works just fine for modules at least. But for python it self the exe installer you might have to code some powershell that silently install it on the remote desktop.
Install modules automatically with Python

import importlib.util
import subprocess
import sys

# List of required modules
required_modules = ['colorama', 'python-whois']

def supports_color():
    """ Check if the terminal supports colors. """
    if os.name == 'nt':  # For Windows
        return True  # Windows consoles support colors
    return sys.stdout.isatty()  # Check if stdout is a terminal

def check_and_install_modules(modules):
    if supports_color():
        print(Fore.YELLOW + "Please wait while we are checking if the correct modules are installed..." + Style.RESET_ALL)
    else:
        print("Please wait while we are checking if the correct modules are installed...")

    for module in modules:
        if importlib.util.find_spec(module) is None:
            if supports_color():
                print(Fore.RED + f"Module '{module}' is not installed. Installing..." + Style.RESET_ALL)
            else:
                print(f"Module '{module}' is not installed. Installing...")
            try:
                subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', module], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
                if supports_color():
                    print(Fore.GREEN + f"Successfully installed '{module}'!" + Style.RESET_ALL)
                else:
                    print(f"Successfully installed '{module}'!")
            except Exception as e:
                if supports_color():
                    print(Fore.RED + f"Failed to install '{module}': {e}" + Style.RESET_ALL)
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to install '{module}': {e}")
        else:
            if supports_color():
                print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + f"Module '{module}' is already installed." + Style.RESET_ALL)
            else:
                print(f"Module '{module}' is already installed.")

# Call the function to check and install modules
check_and_install_modules(required_modules)


Install silently on remote computer python - with Powershell

    # Prompt the user for the remote computer name
    $remoteComputer = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the remote computer name or IP address"

    # Check if the remote computer is reachable
    if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $remoteComputer -Count 2 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Host "The remote computer '$remoteComputer' is not reachable. Please check the name or IP address and try again." -ForegroundColor Red
        exit
    }

    # Create a session to the remote computer
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteComputer

    try {
        # Check if Python is installed
        $pythonInstalled = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
            $pythonPath = "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"  # Adjust to your expected version
            if (Test-Path $pythonPath) {
                & $pythonPath --version
            } else {
                $null
            }
        }

        if (-not $pythonInstalled) {
            Write-Host "Python is not installed on '$remoteComputer'. Installing Python 3.10..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

            # Define variables for installation
            $pythonInstallerUrl = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.13/python-3.10.13.exe"  # Python 3.10 installer URL
            $installerPath = "C:\temp\python-installer.exe"
            $logFilePath = "C:\temp\python-install-log.txt"

            # Create temp directory if it doesn't exist
            Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
                if (-not (Test-Path "C:\temp")) {
                    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\temp" -Force
                }
            }

            # Download and install Python silently
            Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
                Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $using:pythonInstallerUrl -OutFile $using:installerPath
                Start-Process -FilePath $using:installerPath -ArgumentList "/quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0" -Wait -PassThru |
                Tee-Object -FilePath $using:logFilePath
            }

            # Set the PATH environment variable
            Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
                # Add Python to system PATH
                setx /M path "$Env:PATH;C:\Program Files\Python310\" 
                # Update the current session's PATH variable
                $env:PATH = $env:PATH + ";C:\Program Files\Python310\" 
            }

            Write-Host "Python 3.10 installed and PATH updated on '$remoteComputer'." -ForegroundColor Green
        } else {
            Write-Host "Python is currently installed on '$remoteComputer': $pythonInstalled" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    } finally {
        # Clean up the session
        Remove-PSSession -Session $session
    }



